# Sorting an array pulled from database using $obj->select

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, forms

I have inherited a project from another developer that has a bunch of dropdown menus that pull information from the database. The way this is set up is as follows:

```
$agent_list = $obj->select(TABLEPRIFIX.'agent', '*', ['status' =>1 ]);
```

If I am reading this correctly it is basically saying "select table 'the_agent' and grab everything with a status of 1". That part works fine however the dropdown menu that is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Agent</label>
    <select name="agent_id" id="" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($agent_list as $agent) 
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $agent['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($agent['id'] == $agent[0]['agency_id']) ? 'selected': '' ?> ><?php echo $agent['name']; ?></option>
```

Will display all the names in non-alphabetical order. The rows have an id number that is the primary key so that is what creates the order however I would like to be able to sort the array by the "name" column so it will display as alphabetical order. Through my research online I have seen and tried many methods such as using JavaScript, using order(), and ORDER BY. The ORDER BY seems to be the easiest and smoothest way of to accomplish this but I am not able to get it or any other method to work with the way $agent_list is set up. Is it possible to use ORDER BY with the way it is set up or do I need to use another method?

Comment: What are the parameters that `select` method accepts in `$obj->select` ?

Comment: Or there might be some individual order_by method to attach.

Comment: @vivek_23 I am unable to find information online about the $obj->select so I am not certain on what parameters it can accept and I was thinking there might be some sort of order_by method that I could attach but unfortunately I am unable to find anything online as well and everything I have tried isn't working.

Comment: @collapsar Thank you so much you are a genius! Your usort code worked like a charm! If you make this an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @ProfessionallyInept To check the definition, using an IDE would be useful to directly jump to where it was declared as it would reduce the overhead on PHP's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check where `$obj` is set, it might be an instance of a db query class. The constructor of that class (or the definition of the function returning the value assigned to `$obj`) should provide the info how you can specify an `ORDER_BY` clause to be included in the DB query (if at all), which is the preferred way to go.

If that's not an option, sort the php array with a custom sort function:

```
 usort($agent_list, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); });
```

Consult [usort in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for details. Code untested.